# Can't validate files with multer

Tags: node.js, handlebars, multer, express-validator

Невозможно проверить файлы с помощью multer. Вроде подключил и настроил как надо, еще создал папку изображений, в которой сохраняются картинки.
Вот сама иерархия проекта:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Файловое промежуточное ПО, проверяющее загружаемые файлы - file.js

```
let multer = require(`multer`);
let path = require(`path`);

// метод diskStorage - Опредиляем куда и как нам сохранять файл
let storage = multer.diskStorage({
  // А это функция отвечает за то куда мы будем складывать новый файл
  destination(req, file, cb){
    cb(null, `images`)
  },
  // В этой функции мы будем говорить как нам назвать новый файл
  filename(req, file, cb){
    cb(null, `${new Date().toISOString()}-${file.originalname}`)
  }
})

// Форматы принимаемых файлов
let allowedTypes = [`image/png`, `image/jpg`, `image/jpeg`];

// Это валидация для файлов
let fileFilter = (req, file, cb) =>{
  if(allowedTypes.includes(file.mimetype)){
    cb(null, true);
  } else {
    cb(null, false);
  }
}



module.exports = multer({
  storage: storage,
  fileFilter: fileFilter
})
```

Маршрутизатор, на который получен сохраненный файл

```
let {Router} = require(`express`);
let User = require(`../models/user`);

let router = Router();

router.get(`/`, function(req,res){
  res.render(`profile`, {
    title: `Профиль ${req.session.user.login}`,
    user: req.session.user
  })
})



// Сохранения картинки профиля
router.post(`/`, async (req,res)=>{
  let user = await User.findById(req.session.user._id);

  let toChange = {
    login: req.body.login,

  }
  console.log(req.file);

  if(req.file){
    toChange.avatarUrl = ``;
  }
  // Добавления поля к пользователю
  Object.assign(user, toChange);

  await user.save();

  res.redirect(`/profile`);
})



module.exports = router;
```

Файл handlebars с формой, которая отправляет файл от клиента на сервер.

```
<div class="profile">
  <form action="/profile" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <img src="{{user.avatarUrl}}" class="image">
    <input type="file" name="avatar">
    <label for="">Логин</label>
    <input name="login" type="text" placeholder="{{user.login}}">
    <input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="{{csrf}}">

    <button type="submit">Изменить</button>  
  </form>
</div>
```

Но при всех этих настройках выдает ошибку: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Хорошо\Desktop\Node.js\images\2021-08-06T09:31:17.504Z-апукцпукп.png'

Comment: на Stack Overflow на русском вопросы принято задавать **только на русском языке.** Пожалуйста, переведите ваш вопрос на русский язык или воспользуйтесь Stack Overflow на английском.

Comment: в виндовс недопустимо двоеточие в имени файла